# Linker can't find Vulkan & GLFW when using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors, glfw, vulkan

I'm trying to integrate Vulkan, GLM, & GLFW in clion.

After some learning of cmake I thought this would work.

With this cmakelists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(LuxAegisClion)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(LuxAegisClion main.cpp)

target_include_directories(LuxAegisClion PRIVATE
        C:/VulkanSDK/1.3.275.0/Include
        C:/Users/guilh/Documents/Libraries/glfw-3.3.9.bin.WIN64/include
        C:/Users/guilh/Documents/Libraries/glm
)

link_directories(LuxAegisClion PRIVATE
        C:/VulkanSDK/1.3.275.0/Lib
        C:/Users/guilh/Documents/Libraries/glfw-3.3.9.bin.WIN64/lib-vc2022
)

target_link_libraries(LuxAegisClion PRIVATE
        vulkan-1.lib
        glfw3.lib
)
```

...and this code:

```cpp
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE

#include <glm/vec4.hpp>
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Vulkan window", nullptr, nullptr);

    uint32_t extensionCount = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr);

    std::cout << extensionCount << " extensions supported\n";

    glm::mat4 matrix;
    glm::vec4 vec;
    auto test = matrix * vec;

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

...I get this message:

```
====================[ Build | LuxAegisClion | Debug ]===========================
"D:\apps\code apps\CLion\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build D:\CodingProjects\LuxAegisClion\cmake-build-debug --target LuxAegisClion -j 14
[1/1] Linking CXX executable LuxAegisClion.exe
FAILED: LuxAegisClion.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && "D:\apps\code apps\CLion\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE" -g  CMakeFiles/LuxAegisClion.dir/main.cpp.obj -o LuxAegisClion.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libLuxAegisClion.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lvulkan-1  -lglfw3  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
D:\apps\code apps\CLion\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lvulkan-1: No such file or directory
D:\apps\code apps\CLion\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglfw3: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Looks like you want to use `target_link_directories` command, which accepts target name as the first argument and privacy control. The function `link_directories`, which you are actually using, accepts only directories, and for make an effect it should be called before `add_executable`, not after it.

Comment: `C:/Users/guilh/Documents/Libraries/glfw-3.3.9.bin.WIN64/lib-vc2022` looks like binaries for msvc not MinGW. Many times you can  not use msvc binaries for MinGW or vise versa.

Comment: @drescherjm made the change now it presents this:
```
D:\apps\code apps\CLion\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lvulkan-1: No such file or directory
D:\apps\code apps\CLion\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglfw3: No such file or directory
```

Comment: An easy way to get the proper MinGW binaries is to use msys2 to install the latest MinGW and then use `pacman` to install the package from the msys2 repository vulkan is in the repository: [https://packages.msys2.org/search?q=vulkan](https://packages.msys2.org/search?q=vulkan) and so is glfw [https://packages.msys2.org/search?t=pkg&q=glfw](https://packages.msys2.org/search?t=pkg&q=glfw)

Answer (score 0):

After the help provided by @drescherjm, I found the solution, which is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(LuxAegisClion)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(LuxAegisClion main.cpp)

target_include_directories(LuxAegisClion PRIVATE
        C:/VulkanSDK/1.3.275.0/Include
        C:/Users/guilh/Documents/Libraries/glfw-3.3.9.bin.WIN64/include
        C:/Users/guilh/Documents/Libraries/glm
)

target_link_directories(LuxAegisClion PRIVATE
        C:/VulkanSDK/1.3.275.0/Lib
        C:/Users/guilh/Documents/Libraries/glfw-3.3.9.bin.WIN64/lib-mingw-w64
)

target_link_libraries(LuxAegisClion PRIVATE
        vulkan-1.lib
        glfw3.lib
)
```

Basically, I switched to a library that supported MinGW, as that was the compiler CLion was using.